# Scraping the selected value from a dropdown menu

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the selected value in a dropdown menu from a webpage. How do I narrow my scraping down to the correct level?

I've tried a number of different combinations with find & find_all on select, option, option value and selected"".

I want to get the value after selected""> in this html-code:

```
<select name="aar"><option value="2019/2020">2019/2020</option> 
     <option value="2018/2019" selected="">2018/2019</option><option 
     value="2017/2018">2017/2018</option><option
```

I want 2018/2019 as my result

My current code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for i in range(2018,2019):
    url='https://superstats.dk/program?aar={}%2F{}'.format(i,i+1)
    html_doc = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc.content, "lxml")
    aar = soup.find_all("select")
    print(aar)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Css selector to fetch the value with attr `selected`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
for i in range(2018,2019):
    url='https://superstats.dk/program?aar={}%2F{}'.format(i,i+1)
    html_doc = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc.content, "lxml")
    optionval = soup.select_one('option[selected]')['value']
    print(optionval)
```

Output:

> 2018/2019

Answer (score 0):

I coded this for you all you have to do now is print a new line every 9 indexes 
and you'll get all years from that website in a txt file
**Don't forget to install the library I used in the code**

- 2019/2020
- 2018/2019
- 2017/2018
- 2016/2017
- 2015/2016
- and so on

  1. import urllib.request
  2. from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

>

```
url='https://superstats.dk/program?aar={}%2F{}'
html_doc = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

show_select = str(soup.find_all("select"))
file = open("test.txt", "w+") 

for everything in show_select :
    file.write(str(everything))
file.close()

file = open("test.txt", "r")
lines = file.readlines()
number_of_lines = len(lines)

placeholder = 0
each_line = lines[placeholder]

file2 = open("All numbers.txt", "w+")
while placeholder < number_of_lines:
    for number in each_line:
        if number in "0123456789" :
            file2.write(str(number))
            placeholder += 1
        if number == "/":
            file2.write(str(number))
            placeholder += 1            
        else:
            placeholder += 1
            pass

    file2.close()
```